# Perl split and regex query

Tags: regex, perl, split

I have a line of text such as

This "is" a test "of very interesting" problems "that can" be solved

And I'm trying to split it so that my array @goodtext would contain however many strings there are from quoted sections.
So my array would contain the following:

```
$goodtext[0] is
$goodtext[1] of very interesting
$goodtext[2] that can
```

The number of quoted sections in each line varies, unfortunately...

Comment: The core [Text::Balanced](http://perldoc.perl.org/Text/Balanced.html) module will be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Presuming that there can be no sensible nesting

```
my @quoted = $string =~ /"([^"]+)"/g;
```

or, if you need to be able to do some processing while collecting them

```
my @quoted;    
while ($string =~ /"([^"]+)"/g) {      #" (stop faulty markup highlight)
    # ...
    push @quoted, $1;
}
```

Note that we need the closing `"`, even though `[^"]+` will match up to it anyway. This is so that the engine consumes it and gets past it, so the next match of `"` is indeed the next opening one.

If the quotations "*can be "nested" as well*" then you'd want `Text::Balanced`

---

As an aside, note the difference in behavior of the `/g` modifier in list and scalar [contexts](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Context).

- In the list context, imposed by the [list assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54564428/4653379) (to `@quoted` in the first example), with the `/g` modifier the match operator returns a list of all captures, or of all matches if there is no capturing in the pattern (no parens)
- In the scalar context, when evaluated as the `while` condition (for example), its behavior with `/g` is more complex. After a match, the next time the regex runs it continues searching the string from the position of (one after) the previous match, thus iterating through matches.

  Note that we don't need a loop for this (what is a subtle cause for subtle bugs)

  ```
    my $string = q(one simple string);

    $string =~ /(\w+)/g; 
    say $1;               #--> one

    $string =~ /(\w+)g;
    say $1;               #--> simple
  ```

  Without `/g` in either regex we don't get this behavior, but rather `one` is printed both times.

See *Global matching* [in perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Using-regular-expressions-in-Perl), and for instance *`\G` assertion* ([in perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#%5CG-assertion))
and [pos](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pos.html)

Answer (score 3):

Example of using [Text::Balanced](http://perldoc.perl.org/Text/Balanced.html) to extract the quoted substrings:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw/say/;
use Text::Balanced qw/extract_multiple extract_delimited/;

my $test = q{This "is" a test "of very interesting" problems "that can" be solved};

sub just_quotes {
  extract_multiple $_[0], [ sub { extract_delimited $_[0], '"' } ], undef, 1;
}

say for just_quotes $test;
```

this will produce:

```
"is"
"of very interesting"
"that can"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$ a='This "is" a test "of very interesting" problems "that can" be solved'

$ echo $a | perl -lne ' @arr=$_=~/"(.+?)"/g; print join("\n",@arr) '
is
of very interesting
that can

$
```